# Dispatcher stop to invoke

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I'm having an issue while running `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`. A script writes info in a buffer to display in a graph. My `Action` writes data to the graph. The breakpoint on the line `var selection = GraphInformation.Selection;` is hit between 20 and 80 times. Can't find any logic to these numbers. My breakpoint on `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` is always hit. In addition, the UI froze.

```
    public void UpdateDatas(TestResult result, List<Tuple<int, int>> modifiedRows)
    {
        if (GraphInformation.Selection.XAxisData == null || result == null)
        {
            CreateGraphLinesCollection();
            return;
        }

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {

            var selection = GraphInformation.Selection;
            XAxisLabel = selection.XAxisData.ChannelMetadata.DisplayName + GetFormattedUnitOfMeasure(selection.XAxisData.ChannelMetadata);
            Y1AxisLabel = GetYAxisLabel(selection.Y1AxisDataCollection);
            Y2AxisLabel = GetYAxisLabel(selection.Y2AxisDataCollection);
            try
            {
                lock (_graphLinesLock)
                {
                    foreach (var yData in selection.Y1AxisDataCollection)
                        AddGraphLine(Axis.AxisY1, selection.XAxisData, yData, result, modifiedRows);

                    foreach (var yData in selection.Y2AxisDataCollection)
                        AddGraphLine(Axis.AxisY2, selection.XAxisData, yData, result, modifiedRows);

                    RemoveExtraLines();
                }
             }
             finally{
                lock (_graphLinesLock)
                {
                    DoPropertyChanged(() => GraphLines);
                    InitializeMinAndMax();
                    UpdateAxesVisibilities();
                }
             }

        }));

    }
```

I dig StackOverflow but I can't find anything that works for me. I try to add `EventHandler` on `Complete` and `Aborted` to write logs but no logs are written. I also edit the Visual Studio exception to break on all exceptions. Nothing is thrown. I also try to add a `DispatcherPriority`.
Hope anyone has an idea to help.

Comment: What do you mean that works between 20 and 80 times?

Comment: My breakpoint on the line `var selection = GraphInformation.Selection;` is hit between 20 and 80 times. The number of hits is totally random.

Comment: have you used the debbuging from visual studio to find the hot path? i have also been working with plotting data, most of the time the library is trying to do somethings in between, are you doing something with multithreading? why do you lock your Graph?, i would suggest that you check async await funtions, you are starting a task (Action) without knowing what happend with the result

Comment: How ofter are you calling UpdateDatas? Is it called from a background thread at all?

Comment: I lock it to avoid exceptions while accessing Graph info from another thread.  I try to add a breakpoint but the last execution, before the freeze, is complete correctly.

Comment: @DonMiguelSanchez Dispatcher.BeginInvoke does not "start a task".

Comment: @Clemens AppendDatas is called approx. each 250-500ms

Comment: Yes, it's called from another Thread. AppendDatas is plotting data (modifiedRows) to the Graph (current class).

Comment: @Clemens A mistake. I'm talking about UpdateDatas sorry. I will edit my comment.

Comment: @Clemens I will try it ;) Thanks. I have just something to say. The _gephLineLock is always unlocked. I was thinking about a problem during the unlock but it's not.

Comment: I used both methods to avoid the deadlock present in [this post](https://michaelscodingspot.com/c-deadlocks-in-depth-part-1/) but it's still the same.

Comment: Code like this is expensive and likely to suffer from a firehose bug.  Happens when the posted snippet takes longer to execute than the amount of time between BeginInvoke() calls.  The main thread now burns 100% core, trying to keep up but never being able to catch up.  Visible side effects are that it becomes unresponsive to input and stop repainting.

Comment: @HansPassant Hmm I understand. Do you have a proposal to fix it? Else than rewrite everything

Comment: I have an update. I update my object who is lock to create logs. It's locked from the same thread and no deadlock happens. The dispatcher really stops to execute the action present on the BeginIvoke.